# How to make external filterby with certain columns and search box in ui-grid using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have one filterby dropdown and one search textbox. In the dropdown,i am dividing it into two search items i.e,one is "None" which has to filter all the columns in the table(whole table) and second part is containing rest of the column names present in the table which has to filter with respect to their name.
But now it is searching whole table.But i need it to search according to columns also if search keyword is not present in that particular column it should display error message.And on selection of item in dropdown it should refresh the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ui-grid search</title>
    <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script data-require="underscore.js@*" data-semver="1.6.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-open="refreshData()">
    <select  id="filterSearch" ng-model="filterSearch">
            <option value="$">None</option>
            <option value="firstName">First Name</option>
            <option value="lastName">Last Name</option>
            <option value="age">Age</option>
          </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText[filterSearch]" ng-change="refreshData()" placeholder="Search..." />
    <br />
    <br />

    <h3>Filter data for defined columns</h3>
    <div id="grid3" ui-grid="filterGrid3" style="height:150px"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);

//Define a custom filter to search only visible columns (used with grid 3)
app.filter('visibleColumns', function($filter) {
  return function(data, grid, query) {

    matches = [];

    //no filter defined so bail
    if (query === undefined|| query==='') {
      return data;
    }

    query = query.toLowerCase();

    //loop through data items and visible fields searching for match
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < grid.columnDefs.length; j++) {

        var dataItem = data[i];
        var fieldName = grid.columnDefs[j]['field'];
        var renderedData = dataItem[fieldName];

        if(grid.columnDefs[j]['cellFilter']) {
          renderedData = $filter(grid.columnDefs[j]['cellFilter'])(dataItem[fieldName]);
        }

        //as soon as search term is found, add to match and move to next dataItem
        if (renderedData.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(query)>-1) {
          matches.push(dataItem);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return matches;
  }
});

app.filter('yearsToMonths', function () {
  return function (years) {
    return years * 12 + ' months';
  }
})

//Setup the Controller
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.Data = [{
    "firstName": "Adam",
    "lastName": "John",
    "age": 20
  }, {
    "firstName": "Jak",
    "lastName": "Wilson",
    "age": 30
  }, {
    "firstName": "Richard",
    "lastName": "daris",
    "age": 40
  }];

  $scope.filterText;
  $scope.filterGrid3 = {
    "columnDefs": [
      {
        "field": "firstName"
      },
      {
        "field": "lastName"
      },
      {
        "field": "age",
        "cellFilter": "yearsToMonths"
      }
    ]
  }

  $scope.refreshData = function() {

      $scope.filterGrid3.data = $filter('visibleColumns')($scope.Data, $scope.filterGrid3, $scope.filterText);
  };
});
```

plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/iYxMSFVwIW4u8zs6HWLh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Above plunker is not working for search but in this plunker it is working for search for whole table but i also need it to search by columns.Here is the plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/iYxMSFVwIW4u8zs6HWLh?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ui-grid search</title>
    <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script data-require="underscore.js@*" data-semver="1.6.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-open="refreshData()">
    <select  id="filterSearch" ng-model="filterSearch">
            <option value="$">None</option>
            <option value="firstName">First Name</option>
            <option value="lastName">Last Name</option>
            <option value="age">Age</option>
          </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" ng-change="refreshData()" placeholder="Search..." />
    <br />
    <br />

    <h3>Filter data for defined columns</h3>
    <div id="grid3" ui-grid="filterGrid3" style="height:150px"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);

//Define a custom filter to search only visible columns (used with grid 3)
app.filter('visibleColumns', function($filter) {
  return function(data, grid, query) {

    matches = [];

    //no filter defined so bail
    if (query === undefined|| query==='') {
      return data;
    }

    query = query.toLowerCase();

    //loop through data items and visible fields searching for match
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < grid.columnDefs.length; j++) {

        var dataItem = data[i];
        var fieldName = grid.columnDefs[j]['field'];
        var renderedData = dataItem[fieldName];

        if(grid.columnDefs[j]['cellFilter']) {
          renderedData = $filter(grid.columnDefs[j]['cellFilter'])(dataItem[fieldName]);
        }

        //as soon as search term is found, add to match and move to next dataItem
        if (renderedData.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(query)>-1) {
          matches.push(dataItem);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return matches;
  }
});

app.filter('yearsToMonths', function () {
  return function (years) {
    return years * 12 + ' months';
  }
})

//Setup the Controller
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.Data = [{
    "firstName": "Adam",
    "lastName": "John",
    "age": 20
  }, {
    "firstName": "Jak",
    "lastName": "Wilson",
    "age": 30
  }, {
    "firstName": "Richard",
    "lastName": "daris",
    "age": 40
  }];

  $scope.filterText;
  $scope.filterGrid3 = {
    "columnDefs": [
      {
        "field": "firstName"
      },
      {
        "field": "lastName"
      },
      {
        "field": "age",
        "cellFilter": "yearsToMonths"
      }
    ]
  }

  $scope.refreshData = function() {

      $scope.filterGrid3.data = $filter('visibleColumns')($scope.Data, $scope.filterGrid3, $scope.filterText);
  };
});
```